# Rewrite model @property in Factory Boy's object factory

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, factory-boy

I want to find a way to properly test my code with Factory Boy.

There are a model, like this:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    param1 = <some field>
    param1 = <some field>
    param1 = <some field>

    @property
    def is_smth(self):
        <some complicated code that returns boolean>
```

There is a factory for this model:

```
import factory

class MyModelFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    param1 = <some value>
    param2 = <some value>
    param3 = <some value>

    # And here i need to "rewrite" property of the model
    # so that it would always return true
```

Can anyone help me with that? I didn't found mentions about this in factory boy's documentation, and various variants i've tried doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

As Suganthi said, you can using mock.

But I offer another solution:

```
 @classmethod
 def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):   
     with mock.patch('MyModel.is_smth',
                     new_callable=mock.PropertyMock) as m:
         m.return_value = True
         return super()._create(model_class, *args, **kwargs)
```

Just mock property during generation models. It works on `factoryboy==2.5.2`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using mocks?

```
def test_is_smith(self):
    mymodel = MyModel()
    with mock.patch('MyModel.is_smith', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock) as mocked_model:
        mocked_model.return_value = True
        self.assertTrue(mymodel.is_smith)
```

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion of @StasEvseev didn't work in our case. I ended up leveraging the Factory Boy's [post_generation](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#post-generation-hooks) hooks since our property is calculating the value based on other models/data. Hence, building the data needed by `@is_smth` will make it to behave/evaluate as intended when that property is called:

```
class MyModelFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    ...

    @factory.post_generation
    def prepare_data_for_is_smth(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
       # Populate/build here the models/fields needed for your
       # <some complicated code that returns boolean>.
```

Post generation hooks are executed after creating the factory instance. You could further customize the hook's behavior by utilizing the `extracted` and `kwargs` parameters, which are passed in the factory class using the `ATTR__SUBATTR` format (e.g. `MyModelFactory(foo__bar=SOME_VALUE)`.